ajaxform never posts files to controller
When my HTML form contains data-ajax, it seems that any INPUT of type FILE are not sent to the server:
<form id="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Save"
    data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post"
    data-ajax-success="someFunction(data)"
>

    <input type="file" name="partFile" accept=".xlsx" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="this posts without error" />

I submit with JavaScript
$("#foo).submit();

In the receiving controller, HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count always has a count of 0.
But if my form is:
<form id="foo" enctype="multipart/form-data">

and I use jQuery ajax to submit the form, the controller sees the selected file.
Why does data-ajax seem to cause files not to submit with the form?
I've been Googling it awhile, but I keep seeing results on how to submit using AJAX using jQuery (which I have working fine).
